# retain radio button selection and keep div visible until all form fields are complete

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to retain a `radio` button value if clicked and display its associated `div` containing a `form` until all form fields are completed. So if `radio` button "yes" is selected, it displays a `div` that contains a `form`. I need to keep that `div` on the page until the `form`is completely filled out after pressing the `submit` button. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code :

```
<form>
    Show form?
    <input type="radio" id="showform" value="yes" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)">Yes
    <input type="radio" id="showform" value="no" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)">No
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhideForm(showform) {
        if (showform == "yes") {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (showform == "no") {
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $website = "";
    } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*
    [-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }    
    }

    if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
    } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    ?>

        <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo 
    htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <br><br> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <br><br> Website: <input type="text" name="website">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
            <br><br> Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <br><br> Gender:
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>


</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">display form 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it works just fine consider the following code...

```
<div id="div1">
    Succesfull.
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <form>
        <input type="text"><br />
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>


<form> Show form? <input type="radio" id="showform" value="yes" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)" >Yes 
<input type="radio" id="showform" value="no" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)" >No </form> 




<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showhideForm(showform) { if (showform == "yes") { 
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block'; 
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none'; } if (showform == "no") { 
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none'; 
}
 }
  </script>
```

This code works as expected! But if this isn't what you want please explain further

Comment: A few lines of explanation of what the answer tried to achieve conceptually would help any future visitors of the answer.

Comment: I will try to explain what I want to achieve. Basically the main page has two options that are controlled using radio buttons with values , yes and no, clicking yes takes you to a form, no to a different form. Once the form associated with yes is accessed, there are several fields that must be completed. If one or more of the fields in the form is empty, and the submit button is pressed, the form should remain until all fields are complete. At the moment, if some or all fields are empty and the form is submitted, the page displays the radio buttons instead of the incomplete form.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works just fine 
Consider the following code...

```
    <div id="div1">
    Succesfull.
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <form>
        <input type="text"><br />
        <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>


<form> Show form? <input type="radio" id="showform" value="yes" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)" >Yes 
<input type="radio" id="showform" value="no" name="showform" onchange="showhideForm(this.value)" >No </form> 




<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showhideForm(showform) { if (showform == "yes") { 
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block'; 
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none'; } if (showform == "no") { 
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none'; 
}
 }
  </script>
```

If this is not what you want please explain further